# Change Google Sheet trigger frequency based on cell contents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

In my Google Sheet "Watchlist" I have the following Code:

```
    var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmailsAdvanced() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Watchlist");  // To only handle the Watchlist sheet  
  var d = new Date();
  var timeStamp = d.getTime();
  var currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  var startRow = 8;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 19)  // Fetch the range of cells
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues() ;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    if (row[2] === "yes" && row[18] === "" ) {    // Trigger only if Column C is "Yes"
      var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
      var message = row[1];       // Second column
      var emailSent = row[19];
     if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {
      var subject = "Buy Trigger for " + row[3] + " has been reached! Last updated: " + currentTime; // Add "Yes" although by your trigger logic it will always say yes in the email
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 19).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     }
    }   
  }
}
```

This sends an email whenever the respective row in Column C contains "yes" and afterwards writes the text "EMAIL_SENT" into Column S. Once Column S contains "EMAIL_SENT" no further mails are sent. A time-driven trigger set to "every minute" calls this function.

Now I want to add that I can define the trigger frequency in the Google Sheet itself. Therefore I want to be able to define the hourly frequency in Cell B3 and the minute frequency in Cell B4. The script should then programmatically create a trigger using that information, something like: "If Cell H2 = "Yes" then Create trigger using B3 and B4 and send an email every x minute/x hour as long as Column C contains "Yes".

I found this snippet which programmatically creates a trigger but I have no idea how I can reference it to cell contents and overwrite the existing trigger which is set to "every minute":

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction'):   create new trigger
         .timeBase()              :   build time-based trigger
         .everyHours(6)           :   every 6 hours
         .create()                :   creates the trigger
```

The respective Google Sheet can be found here: [Watchlist Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cCb5EOw9zWKpo7OZRTDgvhPEliaXS8serP8oJaIX0YQ/edit?usp=sharing)

So I wrote this onEdit() function now in order to create an installable trigger via a simple onEdit trigger but whenever I change cell B4 this does not create the new trigger as the onEdit trigger appears not to be called. Any idea?

```
function onEdit() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Watchlist");  // To only handle the Watchlist sheet 

// Deletes all triggers in the current project.
 var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
 for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
   ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
 }

// Create new trigger based on B4 minute information
ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmailsAdvanced')
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(sheet.getRange("B4").getValue())
    .create();
}
```

Comment: Instead of a hard coded `6`, use your value. You can use other values from your sheet to determine whether to call `everyHours` or some other time unit, e.g. `if (b3value > 0) { ...`

Comment: Thanks but how do I reference the value of B3 as I cannot just type .everyHours(b3)?

Comment: the code you posted shows how to acquire values from a given worksheet: `someSheet.getRange("someRange").getValue()`. Please review the Apps Script documentation on any methods that are unfamiliar. Some allow for multiple styles of input (technically phrased as 'have multiple method signatures'), e.g. `Sheet.getRange` accepts an "A1" style string, 2-4 numeric values, etc. These should appear in the editor's autocomplete functionality.

Comment: Okay, I managed to do that now. Thanks! However, when I create a trigger with that method how long does it take for the script to recognize that the value in B3 changed and hence the trigger should be changed as well. It does not seem to be OnChange but how long does it take?

Comment: This is a bit of an iterative problem. I now have a function "createTimeDrivenTriggers" which first deletes all triggers and then sets a new one using the info from B4 and calling the function "sendEmailsAdvanced". This however works only if I manually trigger the "createTimeDrivenTriggers" function in the script editor as the function to be called and the trigger are connected with each other. How can I solve that logical recursive problem? I basically always have to create a trigger based on the cell info which then calls the function.

Comment: when you make the trigger, it is made from the value at that instant. It is not a perpertual link, where changes get reflected. If you change the value in b3, you will want to 1) delete the previous trigger you made, and 2) create a new one.

Comment: you could use a simple `onEdit(e)` function (look up "simple triggers" in apps script documentation) to call the time driven creator function when the event range is b3 or b4 on the desired configuration sheet.

Comment: @tehhowch: I added the new code to the original post as it gets messy here in the comments section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167895/discussion-between-stefan-and-tehhowch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple triggers cannot do anything that requires permission, that includes modify triggers. You will need to use an installable onedit:

```
function myFunction() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('bar')
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()).onEdit().create();

}




function bar(e){
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
 for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
   if(triggers[i].getEventType() != ScriptApp.EventType.ON_EDIT){
   ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
   }
 }

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('baz')
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("a1").getValue())
    .create();
}

function baz(){}
```

the job of myFunction could be done in the trigger editor since it is onetime use

This will only work if A1 has a valid number of minutes for a minute trigger: 5,10,15,30
Hours like in your first function would be 1,2,4,6,8,12

With an invalid number the old trigger will be deleted but the new one won't be created and you won't know about it until you get the error email that i believe defaults to once a day at midnight.

You will likely need to make a function that evaluates the value in the range rather than using the range value directly:

...

```
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('baz')
      .timeBased().everyMinutes(
       time(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("a1").getValue()))
      .create();
```

...

```
function time(t){
  switch(t){
    case "A":
      return 5;
    case "B":
      return 10;
    case "C":
      return 15;
    default:
      return 30;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jared. That works perfectly. The only problem I now have when I share this sheet with others and they make their own local copy that in order for it to work they need to run the "sendEmailsAdvanced" function in order to click through that security warning and allow permissions and then run myFunction once but this should be manageable. Thanks again and Happy Easter